# Problem With JSF 1.1 and PopUp

Tags: jsf

I am trying to popup a window when someone clicks a button on the data table.

```
                                    <h:commandButton
                                        action="#{cacheController.popupDetails}"
                                        immediate="false"
                                        onclick="popup()"
                                        value="View Details"
                                         styleClass="submit">
                                    </h:commandButton>
```

The associated popup function is

```
function popup() {
window.open('RDDetails.jsf','popupWindow', 'dependent=yes, menubar=no, toolbar=no, height=500, width=400');
}
```

Now in the new 'RDDetails.jsf" file, I am trying to access the same managedBean cacheController. But the problem is, the pop-up window and JSF lifecycle is not in sync. As a result, the popup first displays blank and when I refresh, it pulls out the proper data.

Is there anyway I can click on a button which will do some processing in the managed bean and then opens a pop up which rerieves the processed data from the managed bean.

I am using JSF 1.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're here basically firing **two** *independent* requests: one associated with the form submit and other which opens the `RDDetails.jsf` in a popup. You'll need to combine this in **one** request. You can achieve this in basically two ways:

1. Get rid of the `onclick` and just add `target="_blank"` to the `<h:form>` so that it get submitted into a new window/tab.
2. Block the default action by adding `return false;` to the `onclick` and do the business logic in the constructor of the bean associated with `RDDetails.jsf`. The only (major) caveat is here that the model won't be updated with the form fields. Thus, you'll need to pass the form fields as request parameters of the popup URL manually with help of JavaScript. You can then make use of managed property entries in the `faces-config.xml` to inject the GET request parameters into the model.

First way is obviously the easiest, but this doesn't give you a "fullworthy" popup/modal dialog. The second way is a bit harder (unless you've already a good grasp on both JavaScript and JSF). I would then consider to look for a component library which provides a ready-to-use popup component.

Comment: I am trying to create the URL from the backing bean like this way - onclick="#{cacheController.url}" and the url will have JSp style parameters ?param=value&param2=value2 etc. Do you think this will work?

Comment: No, you need to pass the url through `window.open()` the same way.

Comment: yes I am doing it that way - here is my getURL method in the backing bean -

 public String getUrl() {
  selectedRD = (RuleDisplayTO) dataTable.getRowData();
  return "window.open('/e2fo/tools/cachetool/test.jsp?name="
    + selectedRD.getName()
    + "','popupWindow', 'dependent=yes, menubar=no, toolbar=no, height=500, width=400');return false;";
 }

Answer (score 0):

See my example:

```
<h:commandLink action="#{controller.myAction}" onmousedown="document.forms['idform'].target='_blank';">
```

I'm using jsf 1.1

Comment: You can also just add `target="_blank"` to the `<h:form>` as outlined in my answer.